# In HTTP specification, what is the string that separates cookies?

Tags: http, http-headers, rfc, httpcookie

Semicolon `;`,  the `Cookie:` string or some other string?

Comment: Related: [Does Set-Cookie ever contain more than one cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872100/), [Is it possible to set more than one cookie with a single Set-Cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880047/)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Inspecting cookies in an HTTP request

The `Cookie:` header has the following syntax:

```
Cookie: <Name> = <Value> { ; <Name> = <Value> }
```

Hence individual cookies are separated [with the semicolon and a space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.2.1).

### Setting cookies in an HTTP response

On the other hand, when setting a cookie in the response, there one cookie per the `Set-Cookie:` header:

```
Set-Cookie: <Name> = <Value> [ ; expires = <Date>] [ ; path = <Path> ] [ ; domain = <Domain> ] // etc…
```

To set multiple cookies the `Set-Cookie` header is repeated in an HTTP response.

---

Notes:

- Have a look [here](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) for a tutorial with examples, and to [RFC 6265 *HTTP State Management Mechanism*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) for a normative reference showing the full details of the syntax.
- The now-obsolete [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) defined an alternate pair of headers `Cookie2` and `Set-Cookie2` which were abandoned.
- The obsoleted versions of the *HTTP State Management Mechanism* ([RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) and [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965)) provided a way to fold multiple `Set-Cookie` (or `Set-Cookie2`) headers into one. However, this folding is not recommended by the latest [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) spec.

Comment: *On the other hand, when setting a cookie in the response, there one cookie per the `Set-Cookie:` header:* **Not true.** In section 4.2.1 of [RFC 2109](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109) one reads *An origin server may include multiple Set-Cookie headers in a response. Note that an intervening gateway could fold multiple such headers into a single header.* In section 4.2.2 of the same RFC one reads *Informally, the Set-Cookie response header comprises the token Set-Cookie:, followed by a comma separated list of one or more cookies.*

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost RFC 2109 was obsoleted by RFC 2965, which in turn was obsoleted by RFC 6265. The latest spec recommends avoiding `Set-Cookie` folding. Both 2109 and 2965 do not support folding in the presented ABNF syntax. Thanks for pointing out this ambiguity. I will fix the RFC reference in my response.

Comment: *Both 2109 and 2965 do not support folding in the presented ABNF syntax.* **Not true** Presented ABNF syntax clearly supports multiple cookies in one `Set-Cookie` header (folding) - see my answer.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Fixed in my answer. Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice the semantics of `1#cookie` syntax rule clearly.

Comment: *Hence individual cookies are separated with the semicolon.* **Not true**. The semicolon in the syntax of `Cookie:` header you present separates each `<Name>=<Value>` pair not each cookie as each cookie can have any number of such pairs.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Section 4.2.2 of RFC 6265 reads: “Each cookie-pair represents a cookie stored by the user agent.”, where `cookie-pair = cookie-name "=" cookie-value`. So, can you please provide supportive evidence for you claim *and* downvote?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost fair enough.

Comment: To clarify; in my comment above starting with *Hence (…)* when I was talking about `<Name>=<Value>` pairs I actually had in mind *attribute-value* pairs comprising *cookie-av* part of cookie as described in section 4.2.2 of RFC 2109. However *cookie-av* (and thus *attribute-value* pairs) is valid only when setting cookie by means of `Set-Cookie:` header not when sending back (in `Cookie:` header) a cookie which had been already set.

Comment: One curious thing is that `Set-Cookie:` header's parsing algorithm described in section *5.2. The Set-Cookie Header* of RFC 6265 does not seem to allow more than one cookie (so called *folded cookies*) in this header although it is allowed in section *4.2.2  Set-Cookie Syntax* of RFC 2109. Till now I was convinced that RFC 6265 is backward compatible with RFC 2109 and RFC 2965 in regard to *consuming* header values which are valid according to these two earlier specifications… Am I missing something?

Comment: "separated with the semicolon" - Although, they are actually separated by semicolon + _space_ (2 chars). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is a comma `,` sign.**

In section 4.2.2 of [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) there's this specification of `Set-Cookie` header

```
   set-cookie      =       "Set-Cookie:" cookies
   cookies         =       1#cookie
```

with the following statement *Informally, the Set-Cookie response header comprises the token Set-Cookie:, followed by a comma separated list of one or more cookies.* (Formally meaning of `#` in the above notation is defined in [RFC 733](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc733.txt) in section *A. NOTATIONAL CONVENTIONS*, point 5

> A construct "#" is defined, similar to "*", as follows:
>
> ```
>               <l>#<m>element
> ```
>
> indicating at least `<l>` and at most `<m>` elements, each  separated by
> one or more commas (",").

Yes, RFC 2109 was obsoleted by RFC 2965, which in turn was obsoleted by [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265).
No, it doesn't change anything in this context as

- most existing HTTP servers and clients support RFC 2109
- RFC 6265 does **not** forbid `Set-Cookie` folding

Comment: It matters a lot. RFC 6265 is supposed to describe what UAs actually do.

Comment: @JulianReschke Well in this case could you please tell us which of popular UAs do **not** handle folded `Set-Cookie` header?

Comment: Piotr, I have no idea, and I don't have said so. I was just pointing out that RFC 6265 is supposed to accurately define how cookies work, as opposed to the older RFCs.

Comment: -1 because this answer directly contradicts the accepted answer, and the author of this answer even admits that it's not a comma in the comments thread of the accepted answer. Shouldn't this be answer be removed altogether??

Comment: RFC 6265 doesn't *forbid* Set-Cookie folding (probably for backward compatibility), but it *discourages* it in the strongest terms using "SHOULD NOT": "Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into a single header field."

Comment: I encountered a server that DID fold Set-Cookie headers recently, so this is definitely a thing that is out in the wild.