# How can I get an array of the keys of all current javascript cookies?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I have links for various products. I am using php to add the product ID from the database as the id value for each link.

```
<a class="order_btn" id="<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></a>
```

I am using the jquery cookie plugin(https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to save the number of times the order button is clicked. I am using the product ID from the id attribute as the key for the saved cookie.

```
$(".order_btn").click(function() {
  var productToAdd = $(this).attr("id");

  if($.cookie("Product-"+productToAdd) >= 1) { //If this is not the first item for the current product
    //Updating the number for the current product 
    var newNum = Number($.cookie("Product-"+productToAdd)) + 1;
    $.cookie("Product-"+productToAdd, newNum);
  } else { //If this the first item for the current product
    //Creating the first number for the current product
    $.cookie("Product-"+productToAdd, 1);
  }
}); //end click function for Order Button
```

On the Cart page, I need to list out the Product Name for each cookie that has saved values. Therefore, I need to be able to get the name of the key for the cookie so I can look up the products name in the database.

How can I get an array that has the keys for all current javascript cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You can list cookies for current domain:

```
function listCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
        aString += i + ' ' + theCookies[i-1] + "\n";
    }
    return aString;
}
```

But you cannot list cookies for other domains for security reasons

Answer posted by DixonD in [How can I list all cookies for the current page with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400759/how-can-i-list-all-cookies-for-the-current-page-with-javascript)

Comment: Will that work for the cookies I have set using the jquery cookie plugin though?

Comment: I am trying to save all the current cookie keys in an array.

Comment: That lists cookies for current *document*, not domain.