# Can Javascript retrieve cookies from response header of current page?

Tags: javascript, security, http

- Cookie is a special type of HTTP header.
- Javascript can retrieve all cookies for the **current** page (e.g.
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3400787/418439).
- However, it is not possible to retrieve the header of the **current**
  page
  ([Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript))
  unless making another request.

Why it is designed in this way? Due to security concern?

Comment: In addition to `document.cookie` you can also access `document.referrer`, `document.contentType` and `document.lastModified`. Why not more? Well, maybe just because it wasn't considered to be useful enought to expose.